# problem accessing records of a foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have a dataset of million entries, its comprised of songs and their artists.

I have

- a track id and
- an artist id.

There are 3 tables

- tracks (track_id, title, artist_id),
- artists(artist_id and artist_name) and
- artist_term (artist_id and term).

Now I want to find artist_id, artist_name and the term for a particular track_id.

How do I find it? to find the artist_id for a track_id, it's simple. I wrote

```
(select artist_id, track_id FROM tracks WHERE tracks.track_id = 'TR12739847';)
```

When I wrote

```
(select artist_name, term FROM tracks t join artists a on t.artist_id = a.artist_id join artist_term at on at.artist_id = a.artist_id WHERE track_id = 'TR12739847';)
```

it shows multiple records on artist name and the term.

When I wrote

```
(select artist_name, term, artist_id, track_id FROM tracks join artists on tracks.artist_id = artists.artist_id join artist_term on artist_term.artist_id = artists.artist_id WHERE tracks.track_id = 'TR12739847';)
```

it says ambiguous artist_id or no such column.

For more reference, the schema of the tables is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tracks (track_id text PRIMARY KEY, title text, release text, year int, duration real, artist_id text);
CREATE TABLE artists (artist_id text, artist_name text);
CREATE TABLE artist_term (artist_id text, term text, FOREIGN KEY(artist_id) REFERENCES artists(artist_id));
```

How do I get to the solution?
Where am I wrong? I might be missing out a very little thing or this might be a very basic question but I am stuck.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I wrote `(select artist_name, term, artist_id, track_id FROM tracks join artists on tracks.artist_id = artists.artist_id join artist_term on artist_term.artist_id = artists.artist_id WHERE tracks.track_id = 'TR12739847';)` it says **ambiguous artist_id or no such column**.

The query is unable to parse since you are joining on tables that have the same common name eg: artist_id is present in artists table and also in artist_term table, so its asking which column should the query refer to when you

```
select artist_name, term, artist_id, track_id
```

To fix this create an alias for the tables you are refering and then prefix the alias to the columns

eg:

```
  select artists.artist_name
       , artist_term.term
       , tracks.artist_id
       , tracks.track_id 
  FROM tracks  
  join artists  
    on tracks.artist_id = artists.artist_id 
  join artist_term 
    on artist_term.artist_id = artists.artist_id 
 WHERE tracks.track_id = 'TR12739847';
```